# Excel - extracting the largest values from a database

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I just entered into a new job and I got a request from my manager.

I want to extract the 3 largest values from an excel (please see example attached) in column C only if a specific condition in column B is OK.
In this particular example, I would like to rank the 3 longest jumps for group A.
I used the formulas in column F.

The problem is that the second line of my table (line 3) does not fulfill the condition, creating an error in the formula as the formula tends to follow the lines one by one.

My question is, how can I make my formula in F go to the next line (from C3 to C4) ?
I would need something like “If error, then go to the next line”.

It seems I cannot do this through the excel functions and I will have to use VBA.
Do you have any indication on how to do this ?
Of course I know I could filter manually from column C and launch the formula then but I would like to automate this task as much as possible.

Thank you very much for your help ! I really appreciate any help :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpcsQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llOWW.png)

I tried different formulas without success. Also searched the internet for similar problems but nothing matching perfectly.

Comment: Please show us the formulas you have tried

Comment: `=AGGREGATE(14;4;(($B$2:$B$7=$F$1)*($C$2:$C$7));E4)` for F4 and copy down

Comment: Try: `=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(C2:C7,F1=B2:B7),1,-1),3)`

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much guys, really appreciate the help ! I will learn more about these Excel functions, they seem useful